# Select distinct values from pd dataframe where one of the column is list-type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table where one of the columns is of a list-type. I would like to select distinct values from the table:

```
pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "a": ["1", "2", "1"],
            "b": [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']],
        }
    )
```

The result should contain only the first two rows from the above table.

I tried pandas unique and drop_duplicates but those don't seem to handle list-type columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the lists to tuples first and apply `.drop_duplicates` afterwards:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(tuple)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   a       b
0  1  (a, b)
1  2  (c, d)
```

---

To convert the tuples back to lists:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "a": ["1", "2", "1"],
                "b": [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']],
            }
        )
    
result = dataframe.iloc[0:2,:]

print(result)

   a       b
0  1  [a, b]
1  2  [c, d]
```

Comment: That's _hardcoded_ "I would like to select distinct values from the table" - which only works here.